# $GF(n,20)$ is prime iff : $GF(n,20) \mid S_{4^{n-1}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let us define recurrence equation as :
>
> $S_n=S_{n-1}^{10}-10\cdot S^8_{n-1}+35\cdot S^6_{n-1}-50\cdot S^4_{n-1}+25\cdot S^2_{n-1}-2$ , with $S_0=12$
>
> and let us define following notation :
>
> $GF(n,20)=20^{2^n}+1$

Now , note that :

$GF(1,20) \mid S_1$ , $GF(2,20) \mid S_4$

$GF(1,20) \nmid S_2$ , $GF(1,20) \nmid S_3$ , $GF(1,20) \nmid S_4$

$GF(2,20) \nmid S_1$ , $GF(2,20) \nmid S_2$ , $GF(2,20) \nmid S_3$

$GF(3,20) \nmid S_1$ , $GF(3,20) \nmid S_2$ , $GF(3,20) \nmid S_3$

So ,one can formulate following assumption :

> $GF(n,20)$  is prime iff : $GF(n,20) \mid S_{4^{n-1}}$ , where $n>0$

My question : What would be the easiest way to prove or disprove this statement ?

P.S.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#Proof_of_correctness) you can find proof of correctness of [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#The_test) .

Mathematica code based on the assumption above (output is set of $GF(n,20)$ primes) :

```
Select[Table[GF = 20^(2^n) + 1;
For[i = 1; s = 12, i <= 4^(n - 1), i++, 
s = Mod[s^10 - 10*s^8 + 35*s^6 - 50*s^4 + 25*s^2 - 2, GF]];
If[s == 0, "GF" <> ToString@n, n], {n, Range[15]}], StringQ]
```

Comment: Anyone thinking of working on this problem would do well to become acquainted with the discussion raised by another question along similar lines, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102568/gfn-6-is-prime-iff-gfn-6-mid-s-n

Comment: From the title I was wondering where the hell you were going with Galois fields and symmetry groups...

Comment: @anon,This notation of Generalized Fermat numbers is proposed by Yves Gallot

Comment: It's totally cool, I just thought it was funny.

Comment: I was also so confused at first...